Visual Studio clear navigation
Is there a possibility to erease whole (cursor) navigation in Visual Studio without restarting the environment?
navigation - "Navigate (cursor) Backward"/"Navigate (cursor) Forward"
erease - make the first position, the one, which will be next visited

I'll be honest with you, I don't understand what you're asking.

I familiarized to use the navigation (the most backward) - i.e. after all mods work, let's get back to the ~main part of the code (root) for today/now, then hold 'alt' and 'left arrow', or just after a few smaller mods., just come back to the method, which starts the whole 'process' - f1() -> f2() -> f3() ... - then the "holding" would be very comfortable as well, but if there was something before you just jump over the correct 'place'...
